# Как метод def __lt__(self, other) сравнивает строки?

Tags: python

Как метод:

```
def __lt__(self, other)
```

сравнивает строки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вас интересует принцип работы то сравнение идет посимвольно ([в лексикографическом порядке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA)). Т.е. код первого символа первой строки сравнивается с кодом первого символа второй строки. Если он меньше возвращаем `True`, если больше возвращаем `False`, если равен переходим к следующему символу.

Алгоритмически это выглядит приблизительно следующим образом:

```
def __lt__(s1, s2):
    N = min(len(s1), len(s2))
    for i in range(N):
        if ord(s1[i]) == ord(s2[i]):
            continue
        else:
            return ord(s1[i]) < ord(s2[i])
    return len(s1) < len(s2)
```

---

Если же вас интересует реализация, то придется смотреть в исходники Python.

---

PS особенности буквы `ё`:

```
> print('е' < 'я')
True

> print('ё' < 'я')
False

> print(ord('ё'), ord('я'))
1105 1103
```

Comment: а что вернется если первая строка подстрока второй? `'12345'` и `'1234567'` если проверка только первые 5 символов проверят? или там внизу еще какой-то return должен быть?

Comment: @Grundy, справедливое замечание, спасибо!